# copy rows to target sheet if col 5 is not blank

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Here is the code I have worked on- I have tried many different combinations and none of them are giving me the desired results- Can you please explain why my code is incorrect?

the code is iterating the the rows looking for rows larger than 0- if so, copy the row to the target sheet- However I am getting the wrong rows copied over?

```js
function try2() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Final');
  var lastrow = sheet2.getLastRow()+1;
  var target = sheet2.getRange(lastrow,1,1,5);
  
  var data = sheet1.getRange('E1:E500').getValues();
  
  for(var i=1; i< data.length; i++) {
    Logger.log(i)
    if (data[i] > 0) {
      Logger.log(data[i])
      
      sheet1.getRange(i, 1, 1, 5).copyTo(target);
    }
  }
  

}
```

I updated the code to have the lastrow & target variables in the for loop with still undesired results.

```js
function try2() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Final');
  
  
  var data = sheet1.getRange('E1:E500').getValues();
  
  for(var i=1; i< data.length; i++) {
    var lastrow = sheet2.getLastRow()+1;
    var target = sheet2.getRange(lastrow,1,1,5);
    //Logger.log(i)
    if (data[i] !== "") {
      Logger.log(data[i])
      
      sheet1.getRange(i, 1, 1, 5).copyTo(target);
    }
  }
  

}
```

Comment: `lastrow` is defined outside of the `for` loop and so is `target`, meaning your code will copy every single row to the *same* target destination every time it iterates through your loop.

Comment: I updated the code and added them to the for loop- still with bad results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Requirement:

Copy data from one sheet to the next free row of another sheet.

---

#### Solution:

```
function try2() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Final');
  var targetLastRow = sheet2.getLastRow() + 1;

  var dataLastRow = sheet1.getLastRow();
  var dataRange = sheet1.getRange(1,5,dataLastRow);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i]) {      
      sheet1.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, 5).copyTo(sheet2.getRange(targetLastRow+i,1));
    }
  }
}
```

---

#### Explanation:

This script will loop through all of the rows in column E on your first sheet, and copy any that aren't blank across to your sheet "Final". By using `dataLastRow` to get the data. You save time over defining a set range `E1:E500`, the script will now only get the necessary amount of rows to run the copy whereas before it was running the `for` loop 500 times no matter what.

The data is copied to `targetLastRow+i`, which is the next available row of sheet "Final", incremented by 1 every time the loop completes.

Comment: strangely enough when I run this it copies all rows over?  on sheet 1 col E i have about 150+ items and only 4 have numbers in that column- It should only copy the 4- but is copying them all?

Comment: With the help of your example I was able to get it to work on my side- Thanks for your help!

Comment: Apologies, I thought you just needed it to check if the column was empty, not actually greater than 0.

Comment: No problem, appreciate the help- it was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Code that worked altering @ross code- Thanks

```js
function try3() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Final');
  var targetLastRow = sheet2.getLastRow() + 1;

  var dataLastRow = sheet1.getLastRow();
  var dataRange = sheet1.getRange(1,5,dataLastRow);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    Logger.log(data[i])
    if (data[i] > 0) { 
     Logger.log(data[i])
      sheet1.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, 5).copyTo(sheet2.getRange(targetLastRow+i,1));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is surprising that your code is actually working... The condition you are using is fundamentally incorrect. data[i] is an array, it shouldn't be evaluated as ">0"... since it is never a number.